# Is the phrase "he sucks in something..." offensive in UK? And US? How this can also be expressed?

Tags: slang, phrase-requests

The literal translation of the slang "He sucks", in some languages, can have a very different meaning.

First: is it offensive or it's ok to say?
Second: how can we say the same in UK/US but with other words and keeping the meaning? It can be a slang too.

Comment: Merriam-Webster calls it "sometimes vulgar"; this isn't very conclusive, but the offensiveness will depend on context. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suck

Comment: The two words "He sucks" could have the same meaning as "He sucks in something" (as in "at doing something"), but definitely do not have the same meaning as "He sucks something in". There's an ambiguity between your question title and the text.

Comment: In AE, *he stinks* is a very close match: He stinks at bat, this traffic stinks, stinks to be you. Yes, it is vulgar to be graphic about what someone does when the lights go down, as it were, providing services you wouldn't mention on a job interview. By extension, the activity puts you in a lowered position, a second-class citizen, a bottom.

Comment: The preposition usually used after *sucks* is *at*, not *in*.

Comment: In UK, we don't say that something sucks, but understand what it means (we do watch movies). We might say "it is awful" or "that's rubbish".

Comment: Expanding on @AndrewLeach’s comment - saying that someone sucked in a fly while snorkeling isn’t necessarily rude. The context is important. Please add some context to your question.

Comment: I am very disappointed with my question being closed. It's clear enough and people answered it very well that it depends of the context, and they also gave examples..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is being used in the 'not very good at' sense, in UK usage it would be vulgar, but it's offensiveness would be contextual. 'I suck at playing Tennis' would be perfectly normal in conversation between acquaintances. 'I am lousy at playing tennis, I am useless at playing tennis, I can't play tennis' would have a similar meaning.

It's not, however, language that would be expected in a formal situation. 'You suck' shouted at a boss' would be rude and potentially career limiting!